# CodeIgniter use CRUD delete and update

Tags: codeigniter, button

I just downloaded [CRUD core file](https://github.com/iyut/CodeIgniter-CRUD-Model)

**Viewer:**

```
<!-- PHP Section -->

    <?php foreach ($results as $result) { ?>

    <tr>
       <td scope="col"><?php echo $result->subject;?> </td>
       <td scope="col"><?php echo $result->type;?> </td>
       <td scope="col"><?php echo $result->neighborhood;?> </td>
       <td scope="col"><?php echo $result->cell;?> </td>
       <td scope="col"><?php echo $result->notes;?> </td>
       <td width="100" scope="col"><?php echo $result->time;?> </td>

       <td width="100" scope="col"><button type="button">Delete</button></td>
       <td width="100" scope="col" ><button type="button">Update</button></td>


    </tr>
```

**Model:**

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    log_message('debug', 'Visitor Model Initialized');
}



public $table = 'data';
public $primary_key = 'data.id';

public function default_select()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
}

public function default_order_by()
{
    $this->db->order_by('time DESC');
}

public function default_join()
{

}
```

I have two buttons in view as you see, I just need to pass row id to controller to delete the row selected, also I need to update the row data when pressed update button.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, your controller is named  as "edit". It means that you must have class **"Edit"** in controller directory CI.
More information read here: [enter link description here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html)

At class **Edit** write two methods:

```
public function Edit($id = null){

    if(!empty($id)){
      //Call function CRUD to Update row with ID = $id
      }
    }

    public function Delete($id = null){
       //TODO
    }
```

Now at URL address you must pass for edit row with ID = 1: *www.yousite.com/edit/1*
for update: *www.yousite.com/update/1* or at view file pass link:

`<a href="www.yousite.com/edit/1">Update</a>`

I want to reiterate that you must read the standard documentation Codeigniter, i gave link above